# Finding the volume of a rotating cross section

Tags: graphing-functions, volume

I have to find the volume of a bounded region as it rotates around the Y-axis. My points are y=6; x=-2; x=2; and y=0. What would be the steps to solving this and the solution? Thank you!

Comment: Step 1: draw a picture.

Answer (score 1):

A rectangle formed by vertices $(-2,0), (2,0), (2,6) \text{ and } (-2,6)$ is symmetrically positioned around the y-axis, and when rotated, gives a cylinder. Simply plug in $r=2-(-2)=4$ and $h=6-0=6$ in $V=\pi r h^2 $ and this gives the answer $96\pi$ sq. units.

Comment: @MackenzieCochrane +1: to L Parker's answer, which seems like a sensible interpretation of your query.  Normally, this would be an integration problem, because you would expect the radius of the generated solid to vary as $y$ varies from $0$ to $6$.  It seems that in this case, the radius is **constant**.  This means, as L Parker's answer indicates, that no integration is necessary.  Therefore, the **begged question** is whether you have omitted pertinent details from your query.